# Getting table row data jQuery

Tags: jquery

Just want to get the table row data and pass it. In my code it seems that it only getting first row data.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sc5N7/40/)

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
    var tableData = $('tr.table').children("td").map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

  $('#test1').val($.trim(tableData[0]));
  $('#test2').val($.trim(tableData[1]));
  $('#test3').val($.trim(tableData[2]));
})
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want. I assume you want to get the row the clicked `.edit` element is contained in? `$('tr.table').children("td")` gets all `td` element of the whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Sc5N7/42/)</kbd>

```
var tableData = $(this).closest('tr.table').children("td").map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

---

Change

```
$('tr.table').children("td") 

//will get all tr.table and it's children td
```

to

```
$(this).closest('tr.table').children("td") 

//this will get closest tr to the current edit button
```

---

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: Please explain the problem and your solution, do not only post code.

Comment: @FelixKling Done Sir .I was updating answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
    var tableData = $(this).closest("tr").children("td").map(function() {
     // by $(this) go to current td then by closest go its closest "tr" then find their td        
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

  $('#test1').val($.trim(tableData[0]));
  $('#test2').val($.trim(tableData[1]));
  $('#test3').val($.trim(tableData[2]));
});
```

**[update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sc5N7/41/)**

reference **[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

Comment: Please explain the problem and your solution, do not only post code.